# Define WP Custom post type areas

Tags: php, jquery, custom-post-type

hopefully my description will be clear!

I'm basically trying to create an area for portfolio work to be displayed. I've created a custom post type in Wordpress and i'd like to bring it through to the front-page.php. I have designated areas for where i'd like the work to be displayed ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqDIq.png)). **The dark grey areas are where i'd like to place the portfolio items ONLY.** Each grey area should show 1 portfolio item

I'm using this script to pull in the custom post type:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'Portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 4 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
echo '<div class="home-recent-thumb">'; the_post_thumbnail(); echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="home-recent-title">'; the_title(); echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="home-recent-copy">'; the_excerpt(); echo '</div>';
endwhile;
?>
```

How do I designate the areas in the php so that it shows 4 posts inside the correct element?

Answer (score 0):

Since your layout isn't necessarily conducive to the traditional "loop" functionailty - meaning, you aren't placing the results next to each other - and you haven't mentioned any outside libraries (like masonry or isotope) - I would just do individual queries for each of the four squares.

For the first custom post type square - it would like:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'post_type' => 'Portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
```

And the second (to nth) would look like:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'post_type' => 'Portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'offset=1' );
```

Where your offset continues to increase. In my mind this continues to stay dynamic and is simple enough for four posts. Else your jumping into just a bunch of additional logic with the other squares.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$portfolioPosts = get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'Portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => 4
]);
//first section
?>
<div class="home-recent-thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail($portfolioPosts[0]->ID); ?></div>
<div class="home-recent-title"><?php echo $portfolioPosts[0]->post_title ?></div>
<div class="home-recent-copy"><?php echo $portfolioPosts[0]->post_excerpt; ?></div>
<?php
//later in code
//second section
?>
<div class="home-recent-thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail($portfolioPosts[1]->ID); ?></div>
<div class="home-recent-title"><?php echo $portfolioPosts[1]->post_title ?></div>
<div class="home-recent-copy"><?php echo $portfolioPosts[1]->post_excerpt; ?></div>
//et cetera
```